# Network firewall and intrusion prevention using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, security

Is it possible to use a single board like the raspberry pi as a firewall and / or an intrusion prevention system ?
Or even use a dedicated OS like clearOS ?

I know the Ethernet speed is a restriction but can all this done through only one Ethernet port anyway ?

Thanks

Comment: Wee bit careful with this question please Kevin - it's absolutely possible to use a single board machine of some kind to create a network security system, but we can't support any questions that aren't Pi-specific here. Would you mind rephrasing the question a little to focus exclusively on Raspberry Pis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's absolutely possible to use a single board machine of some kind to create a network security system. Here is an example:
https://opensource.com/life/16/3/firewall-your-home-network-raspberry-pi and an instructables project showing exactly what you are looking for: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Firewall-and-Intrusion-Detection-Syst/

Comment: The first link since to required a another ethernet interface, but they don't mention that on other tutorial like the instrucables one. I wonder can we do without? cause ethernet though USB will be limited to the USB speed anyway, so I guess there is a massive speed lost ?

Comment: @LowRisk not sure if you still need an answer regarding this, I just wanted to note that on a RPi the USB NIC is likely to be faster than the built in LAN port, see for example https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networkings